# MasterCard Payment Services Integration in magento

Tags: magento, mastercard

I am trying to create magento ecommerce site. I stuck in payment gateway ,really new to payment gateway. I got the merchant id from Mastercard payment gateway, and i choose the hosted checkout method. Now how can i integrate to my magento site. Any help or link will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you go over the documentation for MPGS hosted checkout? https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

Comment: @NAJEEB did you integrated it?

Comment: @NithinJohn yes but i am using plugins now.